# how to save checkboxes values in cakephp using ajax?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery

I want to save the values of the checkbox using ajax.

Here is my current code that I wish to update to use ajax.

here is the view

```
    <?php $i = 0;
        foreach ($summary as $sum) {
            ?>
            <tr class="font-size12">
                <td><p><?php echo $sum['posts']['title']; ?></p></td>
                <td class="width450"><p><?php echo $sum['posts']['content']; ?></p></td>
                <td><p class="margin-left28"><?php echo $sum['members']['username']; ?></p></td>
                <td><p><?php echo $sum['posts']['deadline']; ?></p></td>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->create("Posts", array("action" => "update_checkbox")) ?>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Post.' . $i . '.id', array("type" => "hidden", "label" => false, "value" =>
                        $sum['posts']['id']))
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('Post.' . $i . '.done', array("type" => "checkbox", "label" => false, "value" => "1", "id" => "idCheck[]", "onclick" => "getboxes()"))
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </table>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>
```

the javascript

```
function getboxes(){
    $("idCheck[]").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../../../Controller/PostsController',
            data: { action: 'checkingBox' },
            type: 'post'
//            ,
//            success: function(output) {
//                alert(output);
//            }
        });
    });
}
```

the controller

```
public function update_checkbox() {
        //    debug($this->data);
        $var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->data);
        $this->set("result", $var);
    }
```

the model

```
 public function saveCheckBox($checkbox) {
        debug($checkbox);
        $this->saveAll($checkbox['Post']);
    }
```

edit: I added a listener in the checkbox

Comment: How far have you gotten? Have you put listeners on the checkboxes that fire a function when they're changed? If you've done that, look into the JQuery ajax function. It can send a post request with data, which behaves just like a normal posted form.

Comment: @swiecki yeps I added a listener in the checkbox, but still wont save a value in the DB :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your current code, there are two ways to store check-boxes values into the database.
Either You will have to manipulate the posted data received into your ajax_method()
and make it the array like below

```
[Post] => array(
                [0] => ....
                [1] => ....
                );
```

Then you c an use $this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data);

or you can use the following code to save checkbox values into the database.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Case.CHECK_ID][', array('type' => 'checkbox'));
```

Then you can use saveAll() method.